# How can I print stars in decimals

Tags: javascript

I have a function that would take parameter as whole number or decimals suppose

```
function printStars(n)
```

where n can be 1,1.25,1.5,1,75 etc upto 5.

I have different classes for stars.

```
<i class="icon icon-star-0 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i> (empty)
<i class="icon icon-star-25 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i> (25% filled)
<i class="icon icon-star-50 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i> (50% filled)
<i class="icon icon-star-75 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i> (75% filled)
<i class="icon icon-star-100 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i> (100% filled)
```

I want a code where if i enter the number like `printStars(3.75)`, i will give me the string

```
<i class="icon icon-star-100 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i>
<i class="icon icon-star-100 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i>
<i class="icon icon-star-100 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i>
<i class="icon icon-star-75 margin-right-5 size-icon-15"></i>
```

I made the code but it is not handling decimals. Can anyone guide me? This is my current code.

```
function printStars(n){
    var str=n.toString();
    var splited=str.split('.');
    var a=new Array();
    var html = '';
    a=splited;
    if (a[1]==undefined){
        a[1] = '0';
    }
    if (a[0]>0){
        var filled = Number(a[0]) + Number(1);
    } else {
        var filled = Number(a[0]);
    }

    var left = Number(5) - Number(filled);

    if (a[0]>0){
        for (var i = 1; i <= filled-1; i++){
            if (i==1){
                html += '<i class="icon icon-star-100 margin-left-5"></i>';
            } else {
                html += '<i class="icon icon-star-100"></i>';
            }

        }
        html += '<i class="icon icon-star-'+a[1]+'"></i>';
        for (var i = 1; i <= left; i++){
            html += '<i class="icon icon-star-0"></i>';
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 1; i <= filled; i++){
            if (i==1){
                html += '<i class="icon icon-star-100 margin-left-5"></i>';
            } else {
                html += '<i class="icon icon-star-100"></i>';
            }
        }
        for (var i = 1; i <= left; i++){
            html += '<i class="icon icon-star-0"></i>';
        }
    }

    return html;

    console.log('filled:'+filled);
    console.log('left:'+left);

}
```

But is does not work for numbers below 1.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @Turnip displayed

Comment: and `setItem()` ?

Comment: that was just for local storing. Ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function printStars(n){
    setItem('rating',n);

    var wholestars = Math.floor(n); //Round down to nearest whole
    var extrastar = (Math.round((n-wholestars) * 4) / 4).toFixed(2); //Round to nearest 0.25 (- wholestars)
    var emptystars = 5-Math.ceil(n); //Get empty stars

    var html = '';
    count = 1;

    // Whole Stars
    for (var i = 1; i <= wholestars; i++){
        html += '<i class="icon icon-star-100" onclick="fillstars('+count+')"></i>';
        count++;
    }
    // Extra Star
    if(extrastar!=0) {
        html += '<i class="icon icon-star-'+((extrastar*100).toString())+'" onclick="fillstars('+count+')"><i>';
        count++;
    }
    // Empty Stars
    for (var i = 1; i <= emptystars; i++){
        html += '<i class="icon icon-star-0" onclick="fillstars('+count+')"></i>';
        count++;
    }


    return html;
}
```

Comment: This is be best answer. Thankyou.

Comment: Goood one . ..  .

Comment: @AliZia Not problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can separate your decimal in 2, for example 4.5

```
var x = 4.5
var str=x.toString();
var splited=str.split('.');
var a=new Array();
a=splited;
```

to use the first number(4)  `a[0]` to use the second number(5) `a[1]`

Answer (score 1):

You could get the two parts quite easily like this:

```js
    var n= 3.75;
    var hundreds = Math.floor(n)/1;
    var left = n - Math.floor(n);
    left = left.toString().replace(/0\./, '');
    console.log(hundreds + ',' + left);
```

That will give you a multiple of the '100' blocks and the remainder will be the decimal value.

Then just append the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function printStars (){
            
            var starRate = document.getElementById("StarNumber").value;
            
            var html = '';
            
                for(var i = 1; i <= starRate ; i++) {
                    html+="<i class='fa fa-star'> </i>";
                }
                if (starRate.indexOf('.') > -1){
                    html+="<i class='fa fa-star-half'> </i>";
                    i++;
                }
                while(i <= 5) {
                    html+="<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
                    i++;
                }
            console.log(html);
            document.getElementById("StarContent").innerHTML = html;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="StarContent"></div>

        <input type="text" id="StarNumber" name="StarNumber">
        <button type="button" onclick="printStars();"> PrintStars </button>
```

Comment: Also how would I handle 2.25?

Comment: @AliZia , i have edited the answer, please have a look

Comment: @Punit.... I'd use the classes used by the OP, so that he can use it. Doing that you can then handle 0.25 and 0.75.

Comment: @MattCowley my code is working but I guess a logic error so i cant do below 1

Comment: @AliZia My answer should work for any number, it rounds to the nearest 0.25 and uses the classes you supplied.